# Why I am getting this error with the script in my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menubar

I am trying to fix the problem that I am facing with JQuery LavaLamp Menu Bar in my website by adding the following bunch of code suggested by one of the amazing developers and people in this community:

```
<script>
if ($.browser.version < 9.0 && $.browser.msie) {
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML = '<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery.easing.1.1.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery.preloader.js"></script><script type="text/javascript"  src="./Scripts/jquery.lavalamp.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/lavalamp-config.js"></script>';
}
else {
    document.getElementById("head")[0].innerHTML = '<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery.easing.1.1.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery.preloader.js">';
}

​​</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And in the Visual Studio 2010, I got the following error

> Unterminated string constant

under the following line:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML = '<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery.easing.1.1.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery.preloader.js"></script><script type="text/javascript"  src="./Scripts/jquery.lavalamp.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/lavalamp-config.js"></script>';
```

**So how I can fix this problem?**

**UPDATE #1:**

I updated my code to what you suggested guys and I am still getting the same error. Also, here's a snapshot of the error:

[image]

**UPDATE #2**
I modified my code to let the Master Page includes the following code and I am still getting the same error that shows at the top of the page as shown in the above snapshot.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getInternetExplorerVersion()
    // Returns the version of Internet Explorer or a -1
    // (indicating the use of another browser).
    {
        var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
        if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
            var ua = navigator.userAgent;
            var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
            if (re.exec(ua) != null)
                rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
        }
        return rv;
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 if (getInternetExplorerVersion() < 9.0 && browser_type  = "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML = "<script  type='text/javascript' src='./Scripts/jquery.easing.1.1.js'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='./Scripts/jquery.preloader.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'  src='./Scripts/jquery.lavalamp.js'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='./Scripts/lavalamp-config.js'></script>";
 }  else {
       document.getElementById("head")[0].innerHTML = "<script type='text/javascript' src='./Scripts/jquery.easing.1.1.js'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='./Scripts/jquery.preloader.js'>";
   }
​​</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
</head>
```

Comment: You know `$.browser` is about to get deprecated. Take a look at `$.support`.

Answer (score 1):

The closing script tags are likely being interpreted by the browser as the end of the current script block even though they're inside a string literal, which in turn means that particular string literal is unterminated.

Within your string, instead of

```
'</script>'
```

You can do

```
'<\/script>'
```

(When the JS runs the backslash is ignored.) Or sometimes you see something like:

```
'<' + '/script>'
```

Or replace the `<` with the equivalent character code:

```
'\x3C/script>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Use the below function to get the browser version number

```
   function getInternetExplorerVersion()
    // Returns the version of Internet Explorer or a -1
    // (indicating the use of another browser).
    {
        var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
        if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
            var ua = navigator.userAgent;
            var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
            if (re.exec(ua) != null)
                rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
        }
        return rv;
    }
```

and below for getting the browser name

var browser_type = navigator.appName ("Microsoft Internet Explorer")

so your new function would look like

```
   if (getInternetExplorerVersion() < 9.0 && browser_type  = "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML = "<script  type='text/javascript' src='./Scripts/jquery.easing.1.1.js'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='./Scripts/jquery.preloader.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'  src='./Scripts/jquery.lavalamp.js'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='./Scripts/lavalamp-config.js'></script>";
 }  else {
       document.getElementById("head")[0].innerHTML = "<script type='text/javascript' src='./Scripts/jquery.easing.1.1.js'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='./Scripts/jquery.preloader.js'>";
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but nothing changed with me. Could you please have a look at my updated question?

Comment: Reversing the single and double quotes should make no difference at all. Both are value to enclose html attribute values and both are valid for JS string literals.

Comment: **How to put this in the Master page since I am developing as ASP.NET application?** Should I put all of your code in the `<head>` section

Comment: Does that solved ur issue? If, yes then let me know so that I can tell u where to add that. And marked it as answer :)

Comment: I did not try it because I don't know where to put all the code.

Comment: try putting it in $(document).ready(function(){ // your code})